# checking if combination already exists from list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

As part of learning Python I have set myself some challenges to see the various ways of doing things. My current challenge is to create a list of pairs using list comprehension. Part one is to make a list of pairs where (x,y) must not be the same(x not equal y) and order matters((x,y) not equal (y,x)).

```
return [(x,y) for x in listOfItems for y in listOfItems if not x==y]
```

Using my existing code is it possible to modify it so if (x,y) already exists in the list as (y,x) exclude it from the results? I know I could compare items after words, but I want to see how much control you can have with list comprehension.

I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a generator function here:

```
def func(listOfItems):
    seen = set()  #use set to keep track of already seen items, sets provide O(1) lookup  
    for x in listOfItems:
        for y in listOfItems:
            if x!=y and (y,x) not in seen:
                seen.add((x,y)) 
                yield x,y

>>> lis = [1,2,3,1,2]
>>> list(func(lis))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: I'm curious to how yield works(as I haven't used it in code yet).

Comment: @RMDan `yield` converts a normal function into a generator, they are used for lazy evaluation. Read more about [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: While not the answer I expected, it is better. Teaches me new things about Python and a cleaner way to do code I plan to write.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(seq):
    seen_pairs = set()
    all_pairs = ((x,y) for x in seq for y in seq if x != y)
    for x, y in all_pairs:
        if ((x,y) not in seen_pairs) and ((y,x) not in seen_pairs):
            yield (x,y)
        seen_pairs.add((x,y))
```

Alternatively, you can also use [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) (here:  `all_pairs`) which is like list comprehension, but lazy evaluated. They are *very* helpful, especially when iterating over combinations, [products](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `product` and `ifilter` as well as the `unique_everseen` recipe from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
>>> x = product(x, x)
>>> x = unique_everseen(x)
>>> x = ifilter(lambda z: z[0] != z[1], x)
>>> for y in x:
...     print y
... 
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
```